# How to handle end of file when reading xml file

Tags: c#, xml, file-io

So I am reading a xml file with unknown length and reading each element into a list structure. Right now once I get to the end of the file I continue reading, this causes an exception. Right now I just catch this exception and continue with my life but is there a cleaner way to do this?

```
try
{
    while(!textReader.EOF)
    {
        // Used to store info from each command as they are read from the xml file
        ATAPassThroughCommands command = new ATAPassThroughCommands ();                      
        // the following is just commands being read and their contents being saved
        XmlNodeType node = textReader.NodeType;                                             

        textReader.ReadStartElement( "Command" );
        node = textReader.NodeType;
        name = textReader.ReadElementString( "Name" );
        node = textReader.NodeType;
        CommandListContext.Add(name);
        command.m_Name = name;
        command.m_CMD = Convert .ToByte(textReader.ReadElementString("CMD" ),16);
        command.m_Feature = Convert .ToByte(textReader.ReadElementString("Feature" ),16);

        textReader.ReadEndElement(); //</command>
        m_ATACommands.Add(command);
    }
}
catch ( Exception ex)
{
    //</ATAPassThrough>   TODO: this is an ugly fix come up with something better later
    textReader.ReadEndElement(); 
    //cUtils.DisplayError(ex.Message);
}
```

xml file:

```
<ATAPassThrough>
  <Command>
    <Name>Smart</Name>
    <CMD>B0</CMD>
    <Feature>D0</Feature>
  </Command>
  <Command>
    <Name>Identify</Name>
    <CMD>B1</CMD>
    <Feature>D0</Feature>
  </Command>
    .
    .
    .
    .
</ATAPassThrough>
```

Comment: Any reason you aren't using [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) or [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) (prefered if you have access to .Net 3.5)?

Comment: nope just not familiar with it

Comment: Can you past an example of your XML file?

Comment: added xml file example

Comment: @yawnobleix I'd recommend becoming familiar with it. Serializing and deserializing XML is a solved problem, there's no need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would recomend using XDocument for reading XML data... for instance in your case since you already have a TextReader for your XML you can just pass that into the XDocument.Load method... your entire function above looks like this..

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(textReader);
foreach (var commandXml in doc.Descendants("Command"))
{
    var command = new ATAPassThroughCommands();
    var name = commandXml.Descendants("Name").Single().Value;
    // I'm not sure what this does but it looks important...
    CommandListContext.Add(name); 
    command.m_Name = name;
    command.m_CMD = 
         Convert.ToByte(commandXml.Descendants("CMD").Single().Value, 16);
    command.m_Feature = 
         Convert.ToByte(commandXml.Descendants("Feature").Single().Value, 16);
    m_ATACommands.Add(command);
}
```

Significantly easier.  Let the framework do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: worked perfectly I will probably spend some time learning more about XDocument as it seems to be pretty useful

Comment: It definitely is.  This is called linq to xml if you want to search for info on how to manipulate XML this way.

Answer (score 6):

Probably the easiest way if you have normal and consistant XML is to use the [XML Serializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx).

First Create Objects that match your XML

```
[Serializable()]
public class Command
{
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("Name")]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("CMD")]
  public string Cmd { get; set; }

  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("Feature")]
  public string Feature { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("ATAPassthrough")]
public class CommandCollection
{
  [XmlArrayItem("Command", typeof(Command))]
  public Command[] Command { get; set; }
}
```

The a method to return the `CommandCollection`

```
public class CommandSerializer
{
  public commands Deserialize(string path)
  {
    CommandCollection commands = null;

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CommandCollection ));

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
    reader.ReadToEnd();
    commands = (CommandCollection)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    reader.Close();

    return commands ;
  }
}
```

Not sure if this is *exactly* correct, I don't have the means to test it, but is should be really close.

Comment: FYI, the XML Serializer doesn't need the `[Serializable]` attribute.

Comment: Agreed, I tend to mark classes as `[Serializeable]` when I intent to serialize them (binary, xml, json, etc) lets other programmers know it is going to be serialized.  This allows them to take precautions if changes are required.  Especially if programmers (like me) who like to look at collapsed code, I can tell it should be capable of being serialized without checking inside the class.